# How to identify an MVP for house building?

Tags: scheduling, applications

I am trying to find a minimal viable product for house building company.
I don't know what are the commonly used constraints. Intuitively, I would say that:

- There is a set of tasks. Each task has a processing time. Each task need a set of skills.
- There is precedence constraints (maybe with time lags) between some tasks.
- A set of workers. Each worker has a calendar and a set of skills.
- ...

The problem consists of assigning starting dates and workers to tasks.

If I want to make an app to solve this kind of problems, what papers/ existing apps/ methods should I know?

Edit: I read some papers about the multi-skill variant of the resource constrained project scheduling problem but I am not sure it will be a good model for such an MVP. I am not sure how it will scale with large-size instances.

Comment: hi @Patrick, which papers do you already know? Do you have any background on modeling with mathematical programs (I guess not)?

Comment: Hi @MarcoLübbecke. My background is an introductory course in operations research where I learnt some of the basics about linear programming, integer programming. When searching for similar posts on this forum, I read about constraint programming and its utility for large scale scheduling problems but I don't have any background on this.

Comment: ah, good! then you might even have researched some papers? or identified a closest related problem? the more you write about where you start, the better others can help you with questions.

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke Okay, I will edit my post according to that. I read some papers about the resource constrained project scheduling problem but I am not sure it will be a good model for such an MVP.